# Array definition misunderstanding?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I read [Kip Irvine](http://kipirvine.com/asm/) x86 assembly book and have two questions.

1) What is the meaning of this definition:

```
array2   WORD  5 DUP(3 DUP(?))
```

2) What is the difference between

```
myArray BYTE 10,20,30,40,50,
             60,70,80,90,100
```

and

```
myArray BYTE 10,20,30,40,50
        BYTE 60,70,80,90,100
```

in this array definition?

Comment: what does it produce when you assemble it then disassemble it?

Answer (score 2):

1) As we know the DUP stands for Duplicate. And in this statement, you are creating an Byte array of length 15. This works like this, you are asking the assembler to give you 5 of these (3(?)). And (3(?)) means 3 unknown values.

This can be better explained using this example -

```
array DB 5 DUP(3 DUP('a'), 2 DUP('b'))
```

Here the array will be of length 25 (5*(3+2)). And it will initialized as -

> aaabbaaabbaaabbaaabbaaabb

Which is basically aaabb 5 times. So in short, you made a custom duplicate with different values which are repetitive.

2) That is basically the way you abbreviate the code according to your visual needs. It can be one line itself. Let's say you have an array having around 20 numbers. So it's easier to split them into 3-4 lines.

So a code like this -

```
INVENTORY   DW  0
            DW  0
            DW  0
            DW  0
```

Can also be written as -

```
INVENTORY   DW  0 , 0 , 0 , 0
```

Comment: in question 2 in first case one comma is more than the second case. isnt important?

Comment: The comma is given because we have manually entered a value '60'. So basically, even if the second line was right next to the first one, it would be the same thing.

Comment: @SanVed "Which is basically aaabb 4 times" Shouldn't that be **5** times?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> array2   WORD  5 DUP(3 DUP(?))
> ```

This creates an array of 5*3 words, so 30 bytes in total. None of these bytes will get a defined value because the **?** placeholder means that the assembler assigns the space but does not initialize the contents.

---

```
myArray BYTE 10,20,30,40,50,
             60,70,80,90,100
...
myArray BYTE 10,20,30,40,50
        BYTE 60,70,80,90,100
```

Both these initializer lists declare the same array. In the first case however the list was **not** interrupted by the transition to another line thanks to the added comma. This becomes important when using the LENGTHOF and SIZEOF operators. In the first case LENGTHOF and SIZEOF yield 10, but in the second case they'll give only 5.